# SignalR and AsyncAPI

Tags: signalr, asyncapi

We are trying to document our SignalR Hubs via AsyncAPI.
This is the best example so far we were able to find about SignalR and AsyncAPI:

https://github.com/neuroglia-io/AsyncApi/issues/3

When we apply this scenario to our code in a similar manner, we can create a specification, but this specification results in "Empty or invalid document" in asyncapi studio. I cannot understand why.

Another question is, AsyncApi seems to support SignalR because WebSockets is what SignalR uses, but not necessarily. (In our case, SignalR might fall back to Server Events / Long Polling depending on firewall configuration.) Does that mean that the AsycnApi UI will be useless for us when that happens? Or am I mixing things here?

Comment: Update to my first question: After having upgraded the AsyncAPI libraries I was able to get rid of "Empty or invalid document" error message and create the specification.